# Ubuntu 20.04 Network Manager constantly crashes and restarts

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager, crash

So, starting a few weeks ago the network manager of my Ubuntu 20.04 Laptop sometimes decides to keep crashing and restarts again - it happened 4-5 times so far.

The effect is that I cannot access the network and it shows by the WiFi-Tab constantly diapperaring and reappearing in the settings window and in the upper-right corner drop down menu the wifi and mobile broadband disappear and appear repetedly.

It disappears for about 0.5 seconds and appears for about 1 second again.

Restarting the network manager through `sudo service network-manager restart` or `nmcli radio wifi off` has absolutly no effect. (The second command tells me that the network manager is not started, when I perform it when the wifi disappeared - so it should be connected to that.

I am a total newbie to the underlyings of Ubuntu & Co. and only solved it with a restart so far.

Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve the issue?

Network controller as of `lspci -nn` is Intel Corporation Wireless 7260

I will add the system log after restarting the laptop and having access to the internet again.

This is an excerpt of the syslog. I cut it where I think it started and at the end due to character limit.

```
Jun  1 17:46:56 unknown systemd[1834]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Jun  1 17:51:20 unknown dbus-daemon[1015]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.2304' (uid=1000 pid=27097 comm="nautilus ./ " label="unconfined")
Jun  1 17:51:20 unknown systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jun  1 17:51:20 unknown dbus-daemon[1015]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun  1 17:51:20 unknown systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun  1 17:51:50 unknown systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Jun  1 17:54:39 unknown dbus-daemon[1015]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.2306' (uid=1000 pid=27210 comm="nautilus ./ " label="unconfined")
Jun  1 17:54:39 unknown systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jun  1 17:54:39 unknown dbus-daemon[1015]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun  1 17:54:39 unknown systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun  1 17:54:56 unknown systemd[1834]: vte-spawn-df69db62-1c0f-4062-af35-82e6aaa9b696.scope: Succeeded.
Jun  1 17:54:56 unknown dbus-daemon[1943]: [session uid=1000 pid=1943] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=1000 pid=1934 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Jun  1 17:54:56 unknown systemd[1834]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
Jun  1 17:54:56 unknown dbus-daemon[1943]: [session uid=1000 pid=1943] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
Jun  1 17:54:56 unknown systemd[1834]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Jun  1 17:55:09 unknown systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Jun  1 17:55:27 unknown tracker-store[27311]: OK
Jun  1 17:55:27 unknown systemd[1834]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Jun  1 17:56:56 unknown dbus-daemon[1943]: [session uid=1000 pid=1943] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=1000 pid=1934 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Jun  1 17:56:56 unknown systemd[1834]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
Jun  1 17:56:56 unknown dbus-daemon[1943]: [session uid=1000 pid=1943] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
Jun  1 17:56:56 unknown systemd[1834]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Jun  1 17:56:58 unknown systemd[1834]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Succeeded.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.0253] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.0254] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.0259] device (cdc-wdm1): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.0263] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.0265] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.848955] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.851200] audit: type=1107 audit(1622534223.022:140): pid=1015 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.20" mask="receive" pid=3626 label="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" peer_pid=1044 peer_label="unconfined"
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.851200]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.853377] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown ModemManager[1101]: [/dev/cdc-wdm1] channel destroyed
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.857314] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown whoopsie[1778]: [17:57:03] offline
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.861396] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown dbus-daemon[1015]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=1017 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.874679] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown dbus-daemon[1015]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.895546] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.898928] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.903450] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 40:31:3c:d1:3f:6d by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=40:31:3c:d1:3f:6d reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44124.920332] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <warn>  [1622534223.1409] sup-iface[0x55bd1f8f7300,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.1411] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.1417] device (wlp3s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown acvpnagent[1064]: A network interface has gone down.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown acvpnagent[1064]: IP addresses from active interfaces: tun0: 2001:62A:4:31:77:80:71:128, 77.80.71.128, FE80:0:0:0:F376:7D9:4E55:CC53
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Withdrawing address record for fde9:1bc2:b6f8::387 on wlp3s0.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Withdrawing address record for fde9:1bc2:b6f8:0:3c41:7746:3675:3042 on wlp3s0.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Withdrawing address record for fde9:1bc2:b6f8:0:747e:52:b1bb:7773 on wlp3s0.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fde9:1bc2:b6f8:0:747e:52:b1bb:7773.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::e802:29b:8733:fe0c.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Registering new address record for fe80::e802:29b:8733:fe0c on wlp3s0.*.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::e802:29b:8733:fe0c on wlp3s0.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::e802:29b:8733:fe0c.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown whoopsie[1778]: [17:57:03] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.1666] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.1666] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.1670] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.1670] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown whoopsie[1778]: [17:57:03] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.146 on wlp3s0.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.146.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown avahi-daemon[1012]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown whoopsie[1778]: [17:57:03] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534223.1770] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown whoopsie[1778]: [17:57:03] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44125.015148] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown wpa_supplicant[1050]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown wpa_supplicant[1050]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown kernel: [44125.367553] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: g_dbus_connection_emit_signal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: Error adding children to desktop: desktopGrid is undefined
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.906448] validate_nla: 6 callbacks suppressed
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.906451] netlink: 'svpn_x86_64': attribute type 6 has an invalid length.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.906454] netlink: 'svpn_x86_64': attribute type 4 has an invalid length.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.906674] netlink: 'svpn_x86_64': attribute type 6 has an invalid length.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.906677] netlink: 'svpn_x86_64': attribute type 4 has an invalid length.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.906833] netlink: 'svpn_x86_64': attribute type 6 has an invalid length.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.906834] netlink: 'svpn_x86_64': attribute type 4 has an invalid length.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.907942] netlink: 'svpn_x86_64': attribute type 6 has an invalid length.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.907945] netlink: 'svpn_x86_64': attribute type 4 has an invalid length.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.908195] netlink: 'svpn_x86_64': attribute type 6 has an invalid length.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kernel: [44125.908199] netlink: 'svpn_x86_64': attribute type 4 has an invalid length.
Jun  1 17:57:03 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: message repeated 16 times: [ Error adding children to desktop: desktopGrid is undefined]
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown acvpnagent[1064]: The network interface for the VPN connection has gone down.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown acvpnagent[1064]: IP addresses from active interfaces:
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown acvpnagent[1064]: Function: applyHostConfigForNoVpn File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 12751 No network interface is available, cannot determine potential public addresses.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown acvpnagent[1064]: Current network state: No network interface
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown acvpnagent[1064]: Function: applyHostConfigForNoVpn File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 12751 No network interface is available, cannot determine potential public addresses.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534224.1032] device (tun0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: Removing a network device that was not added
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Succeeded.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager Wait Online.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager Wait Online...
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534224.1411] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: Removing a network device that was not added
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: Object St.BoxLayout (0x564c3ed3c050), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: == Stack trace for context 0x564c3bfcf6f0 ==
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[1017]: <info>  [1622534224.2244] exiting (success)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #0   7ffe84941700 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:776 (1d1a01720538 @ 22)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #1   564c40843b48 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:680 (1d1a01720088 @ 27)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #2   564c40843a88 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:263 (143e09ede20 @ 147)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #3   7ffe849426a0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:253 (143e09edda8 @ 118)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #4   7ffe84942760 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1776 (10d7c5912b50 @ 20)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #5   7ffe84942870 b   self-hosted:266 (1d352eaacb50 @ 259)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #6   564c408439f0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1775 (10d7c5912ad8 @ 102)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #7   564c40843958 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1763 (10d7c5912a60 @ 18)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: == Stack trace for context 0x564c3bfcf6f0 ==
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #0   564c40843b48 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:693 (1d1a01720088 @ 288)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: clutter_container_get_children: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #1   564c40843a88 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:263 (143e09ede20 @ 147)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #2   7ffe849426a0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:253 (143e09edda8 @ 118)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #3   7ffe84942760 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1776 (10d7c5912b50 @ 20)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #4   7ffe84942870 b   self-hosted:266 (1d352eaacb50 @ 259)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: Object St.BoxLayout (0x564c3ed3c050), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #5   564c408439f0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1775 (10d7c5912ad8 @ 102)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #6   564c40843958 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1763 (10d7c5912a60 @ 18)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: == Stack trace for context 0x564c3bfcf6f0 ==
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #0   564c40843b48 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:693 (1d1a01720088 @ 288)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #1   564c40843a88 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:263 (143e09ede20 @ 147)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #2   7ffe849426a0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:253 (143e09edda8 @ 118)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #3   7ffe84942760 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1776 (10d7c5912b50 @ 20)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: Object .Gjs_ui_popupMenu_PopupMenuItem (0x564c3ed684d0), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #4   7ffe84942870 b   self-hosted:266 (1d352eaacb50 @ 259)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #5   564c408439f0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1775 (10d7c5912ad8 @ 102)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: #6   564c40843958 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1763 (10d7c5912a60 @ 18)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: JS ERROR: Error: Argument 'child' (type interface) may not be null#012moveMenuItem@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:693:22#012_updateForConnection@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:263:28#012checkConnection@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:253:18#012_deviceChanged/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1776:25#012_deviceChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1775:31#012_deviceAdded/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1763:22
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: Removing a network device that was not added
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown gnome-shell[2247]: message repeated 2 times: [ Removing a network device that was not added]
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Succeeded.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kdeconnectd.desktop[2451]: "Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying"
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.3013] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (after a restart)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.3015] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.3050] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.3144] manager[0x5557e4607010]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.3145] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown dbus-daemon[1015]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.2309' (uid=0 pid=27436 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kdeconnectd.desktop[2451]: propsReply "No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties” on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager"
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kdeconnectd.desktop[2451]: nmReply "No such interface “org.freedesktop.NetworkManager” on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager"
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown kdeconnectd.desktop[2451]: "Object path cannot be empty"
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown dbus-daemon[1015]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4434] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4435] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "unknown"
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4441] dns-mgr[0x5557e45e6290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4478] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4483] rfkill0: found WWAN radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/rfkill/rfkill0) (platform driver thinkpad_acpi)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4489] manager[0x5557e4607010]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4498] manager[0x5557e4607010]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4545] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4552] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4560] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4566] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4573] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4576] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4578] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4579] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4589] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4613] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4614] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4614] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4614] ifupdown:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4618] ifupdown:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4841] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4844] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4863] manager: (br-ae56371bc915): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4932] device (br-ae56371bc915): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4971] device (br-ae56371bc915): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.4987] device (br-ae56371bc915): Activation: starting connection 'br-ae56371bc915' (398cee62-5b9a-44ff-a658-8eeb3d693740)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.5000] manager: (docker0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.5041] device (docker0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.5056] device (docker0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.5069] device (docker0): Activation: starting connection 'docker0' (17f7b157-afd0-43ff-8363-d914c5e7e2d8)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.5079] manager: (enp0s25): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.5091] device (enp0s25): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.5120] device (wlp3s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.5127] manager: (wlp3s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.5140] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <warn>  [1622534224.7585] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.7756] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <warn>  [1622534224.7905] sleep-monitor-sd: inhibit: failed (GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running)
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.7920] device (br-ae56371bc915): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.7926] device (br-ae56371bc915): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.7932] device (docker0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.7937] device (docker0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.7944] device (br-ae56371bc915): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.7948] device (br-ae56371bc915): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.7960] device (docker0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.7963] device (docker0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.8128] device (br-ae56371bc915): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.8131] device (br-ae56371bc915): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.8136] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.8150] device (br-ae56371bc915): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun  1 17:57:04 unknown NetworkManager[27436]: <info>  [1622534224.8448] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
```